# react-navigation header collapse animation with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-collapsible

I am investigating if the header in `react-navigation` can be animated similar to the most widely used social applications like Twitter, etc.

For this purpose recently, I encountered [coinbase's example which is given here](https://github.com/coinbase/CBTabViewExample).

My questions are:

- **In general, how the react-navigation header can be animated?**
- **Specifically, how to blend the Coinbase example with the react-navigation?**

Similarly, I could not find any clean example for react-navigation usage with [react-navigation-collapsible](https://github.com/benevbright/react-navigation-collapsible) either.

So any atomic example code is appreciated.

Comment: An explicit example of the behavior you're looking for would be great. But I don't think that it's possible. I think that the ability to animate things is one of the main selling points for react-native-navigation, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: can you attach a video example of coinbase collapsible header?

Comment: Did I understand your problem correctly ? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Bigood. Yes you and Thomas got it right. But the problem is I was already at the state you did (like the snack) or what Thomas did. On the contrary what I need is a repo blending Coinbase’s code and react-navigation together. 
Being the first to answer I marked other answer. But I am ready to reset a new bounty for the exact answer. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Oh you're right, first answer is always the best. Next time, I'll just quote the docs too instead of digging the problem. Good luck with that!

Comment: Sorry @Bigood, they are equally "not" I was looking for. So what should had I done? Should I had chosen the snack and youtube? Let me repeat, I am ok to open a new bounty, for a blended solution of Coinbase and react-navigation. And anything "not" providing that are equally "not" complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

```
const progress = Animated.add(scene.progress.current, scene.progress.next || 0);

const opacity = progress.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
  outputRange: [0, 1, 0],
});

return (
  <Animated.View style={{ opacity }}>{/* Header content */}</Animated.View>
);
```

From `react-navigation` documentation  above code snippet should give a clue.

Answer (score 1):

[I made a gif of the repo you linked to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ChAv.gif), and [the associated snack](https://snack.expo.io/Hk5-jOtIu).

I had a similar need a while ago, and stumbled upon this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xutPT1oZL2M

This video show a lot more complicated transition, but is similar to the way it's done in your Coinbase example:

- Use your own `Views` to create this effect
- Use (or not) an animation library to interpolate opacities of elements & positioning based on the `Scrollview`'s current scroll position

All documentation I found at that time on ReactNavigation is about transitioning views / title or else while navigation is occurring. I understand that you don't want to avoid ReactNavigation on a particular screen just to make an animation.

Now, based on this, you might try to animate a custom component, passed in your Screen's `navigationOptions`, which would apply a transition (opacity or whatever) to its child component, based on a props passed with `ReactNavigation` state mechanism and [its dispatch method](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#dispatch).

Not tested pseudo code, to show the idea:

```
class ScreenWithAnimatedNavBar extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    headerTitle: <CustomNavbar shouldDisplayTitle={navigation.state.params.shouldDisplayTitle} title="Your title" />,
  })
  ...
  render() {
     <ScrollView onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
       ...
  }
  
  handleScroll (event) => {
    //Decide whether you should trigger the animation, based on event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y and your threshold
    //Dispatch the animation in ReactNavigation's state if needed
    // https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#setparams
    navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.setParams({ shouldDisplayTitle: true | false }));

  }
```

With a `CustomNavbar` triggering an animation based on `shouldDisplayTitle` props (not illustrated, as not relevant - see how it's done in the video or in Coinbase example).

---

If the animation doesn't rely on the scroll position value - I mean it'll trigger back and forth only at a certain threshold, not directly following user finger - you won't dispatch to often, and it shouldn't be to laggy. If it somehow is, then you should rely on non-blocking code for animation (see the linked video for an example), and / or shift on custom views to have total control.